# Add custom image styles to media browser display options

Tags: media

I'm using the Media module in a project.

I've defined several custom image styles and would like to add them to the list of display options in the media browser. However, I can't find a way to do so.
[image: Displays default options]

Reading through issues similar to mine, I found [this thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/1092444) which suggested using hook_styles_default_presets() to render the options. But even with clearing caches, I'm unable to get my custom image styles to display as formatting options.

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial ended up answering my question:
http://figure-w.co.uk/drupal-how-do-you-make-a-new-image-style-appear-in-the-media-browser/

- Install the Entity View Mode module
- Add new view modes
- Configure display settings for view modes